# ScreenToClient keeps setting point value to entire screen resolution

Tags: c++, winforms

I made a few functions so that when you click on a window it drags the window (like when you drag the title bar on regular windows).
However, whenever I try to drag it, it keeps going to coordinates 0,0 on my screen. (You'll understand the title once you see the code.) I tried IF statements but the window still goes to 0,0 when I drag it (I can't get it to work properly). After I try to drag it a second time from there, it works perfectly (just for that time). Then it goes back to coordinates 0,0 on the screen if I try to drag it again and it keeps on going like that.

Title Bar code to assign events to functions:

```
this->menuStrip1->MouseMove += gcnew MouseEventHandler(this, &CPPGUIForm::MoveWindow);
this->menuStrip1->MouseDown += gcnew MouseEventHandler(this, &CPPGUIForm::titleBarOnClicked);
this->menuStrip1->MouseUp += gcnew MouseEventHandler(this, &CPPGUIForm::titleBarOnReleased);
this->menuStrip1->MouseLeave += gcnew EventHandler(this, &CPPGUIForm::titleBarMouseLeave);
```

MoveWindow function:

```
private:
    void MoveWindow(Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e){
        POINT p;
        GetCursorPos(&p);
        if (mClicked == true){
                this->Location = System::Drawing::Point(p.x - mouseXLocOnWindow, p.y - mouseYLocOnWindow);


        }

    }
```

Title bar click and release functions:

```
private:
    void titleBarOnClicked(Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e){
        HWND hwnd;
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

        mouseXLocOnWindow = pt.x;
        mouseYLocOnWindow = pt.y;
        mClicked = true;
    }
private:
    void titleBarOnReleased(Object^ sender, MouseEventArgs^ e){
        mClicked = false;
    }
```

Title bar mouse leave function (to fix a bug):

```
private:
    void titleBarMouseLeave(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e){
        mClicked = false;
    }
```

Please tell me if you need more info in this post.

Comment: That's not c++. You need `c++-cli` or `c++-clr` tag, I don't know which is which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `titleBarOnClicked()` function, `hwnd` is uninitialized.

I think you want something like:

```
HWND hwnd = static_cast<HWND>(this->Handle.ToPointer());
```